# Why can I not add margins to my form?

Tags: css, forms

This is the HTML

```
        <div id="header">
        </div> <!-- end header -->

        <div id="main">
            <div id="stylized" class="myform">
            <form id="form" name="form">
                <label>Name
                <span class="small">of company, business, etc...</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

                <label>Status Message
                <span class="small">Max 40 Characters</span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="statusmessage" id="statusmessage">

                <label>URL to Menu
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="url" id="url"/>

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                <div class="spacer">
                </div>
            </form><!-- end form -->

            <div id="stylized1" class="myform1">
                <form id="form1" name="form">
                <label>Street Address 
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="stretaddress" id="streetaddress"/>

                <label>City
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city"/>

                <label>State
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="state" id="state"/>

                <label>ZIP
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"/>

                <div class="spacer">
                </div>
                </form><!-- end form1-->
            </div><!-- end stylized -->

        </div><!-- end main -->
    </div><!-- end container -->

</body>
    </head>
```

This is the CSS

```
#container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 147px;
    background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    height: 653px;
    background: url(images/main.png) no-repeat;
}

#form {
    color: #c4c1c1;
    margin: 100px 20px 0px 10px;
}

.spacer{
    clear:both;
    height:1px;
}

#stylized{
    border:solid 2px #c4c1c1;
}

#stylized label{
    display:block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:140px;
    margin: 2px 0 0px 10px;
}

#stylized .small{
    color:#c4c1c1;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    width:140px;
 }

#stylized input{
    float:left;
    font-size:15px;
     padding:5px 25px;
     border:solid 1px #c4c1c1;
     width:200px;
     margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
 }

#stylized button{
    clear:both;
    margin:133px 0 0px 100px;
    width:125px;
    height:31px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:3px;
    color:4b4b4b;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

 #stylized1{
     position: relative;   
     margin: -1600px 0px 10px 450px; 
 }
```

The top margin, no matter how many times I change it, never has the correct coordinates. Every time I change the margin, it just goes back to the same place visually. How come? Is it because of the `#container` width? Or do I need some code? I'm fairly new to this. Thanks for your help.

```
#stylized1 label{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:140px;
    color:#c4c1c1;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#stylized1 input{
    font-size:15px;
    padding:5px 25px;
    border:solid 1px #c4c1c1;
    width:200px;
    margin:0px 0px 20px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Need some HTML too so we know what we're working with. Try setting up a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i guess it depend's on how your div's are placed on the page. can you put more information about that?

Comment: try setting up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), otherwise it's work you *'deliver'* to us...

Comment: oh and... your head closing (`</head>`) can't be positioned after the body!

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste are your enemy. I doubt you want duplicate forms, one or each half of the form entry. Also, you are using position relative all over the place. If you are doing that then you are probably doing something wrong. In this solution I floated the two entry divs to the left. You can adjust the top-margin on stylized1 to position it. I also cleaned up a lot of your html structure.

I was kind of assuming you were editing top margin on the element with -1600px, but if I am wrong please let me know which one you were editing margins on.

http://jsfiddle.net/fVh23/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div> <!-- end header -->

    <div id="main">
        <form id="form" name="form">
            <div id="stylized">

                <label>Name
                <span class="small">of company, business, etc...</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

                <label>Status Message
                <span class="small">Max 40 Characters</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="statusmessage" id="statusmessage">

                <label>URL to Menu</label>
                <input type="text" name="url" id="url"/>

            </div> <!-- end stylized -->

            <div id="stylized1">

                <label>Street Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="stretaddress" id="streetaddress"/>

                <label>City</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city"/>

                <label>State</label>
                <input type="text" name="state" id="state"/>

                <label>ZIP</label>
                <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"/>

            </div><!-- end stylized1 -->
            <br style="clear: both;" />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <div class="spacer">

        </form><!-- end form1-->
    </div><!-- end main -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. One more question, with your code, which top margin do I adjust in order or me to position it correctly on my main image? The form fields are at the top of the image and I would like to position the form in the middle. Thank you again

Comment: Sorry I disappeared. Kid was throwing up all night. I don't know what 'the form fields are at the top of the image` means. There are no images in your code.

Comment: >I'm sorry to hear about that. I hope they feel better. :/                                                                      #main {
    position: relative;
    height: 653px;
    background: url(images/main.png) no-repeat;
} The form that you made appears at the top of that image that I uploaded. Is there any way to position the whole form, not the individual labels/inputs?

Comment: I think I see. Just modify the margin properties of #form. http://jsfiddle.net/fVh23/2/

Comment: Thank you so much. I was also wondering...when using jsfiddle, how do I upload images and make them appear? For some reason, I cannot see the pictures that I use as backgrounds

Comment: As long as the links are correct (you will have to use full urls like `http://mysite.com/myimage.png`) they should work. A nice placeholder image site is http://placehold.it. http://jsfiddle.net/fVh23/4/

Comment: Thank you. I was using them as uploaded on my computer. Should they be positioned the same when compared to files on the computer/hosted images?